# String problem / Select all values > 8000 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select all values bigger than 8000 within a pandas dataframe.

`new_df = df.loc[df['GM'] > 8000]`

However, it is not working. I think the problem is, that the value comes from an Excel file and the number is interpreted as string e.g. "1.111,52". Do you know how I can convert such a string to float / int in order to compare it properly?

Comment: why "is it not working"? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the documentation of [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html):

> Thousands separator for parsing string columns to numeric. Note that this parameter is only necessary for columns stored as TEXT in Excel, any numeric columns will automatically be parsed, regardless of display format.

This means that `pandas` checks the type of the format stored in excel. If this was `numeric` in Excel, the conversion should go correct. If your column was `string`, try to use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', thousands='.')
```

---

If you have a `csv` file, you can solve this by specifying `thousands` + `decimal` character:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can see value of `df.dtypes` to see what is the type of each column. Then, if the column type is not as you want to, you can change it by `df['GM'].astype(float)`, and then `new_df = df.loc[df['GM'].astype(float) > 8000]` should work as you want to.

Comment: This should work, but it keeps the original column as string since it converts the column to float only for the select condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert entire column data type to numeric

```
import pandas as pd
df['GM'] = pd.to_numeric(df['GM'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the data type of your column by using `type` function. In order to convert it to float use `astype` function as follows:

```
df['GM'].astype(float)
```